# Busca registros que referencia a mesma tabela

Tags: postgresql

Possuo uma tabela que ela possui uma fk para ela mesma.
O sentido disso é montar um histórico dos registros anteriores, então eu a tabela possui a coluna id e id_anterior, sendo o id_anterior fk para a coluna id.
O problema é que não consigo buscar mais de um registro, somente uma row.

Exemplo:

```
table_historico

id |  id_anterior
1  |  NULL
2  |  1
3  |  2
```

Minhas tentativas foram:

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.id_anterior, p2.id, p2.id_anterior
FROM table_historico p1
LEFT JOIN table_historico p2 ON p1.id_anterior = p2.id
WHERE p1.id = 3
```

Comment: "somente uma row" que você recebe é na consulta direto no banco ou no código? se for no código o problema pode não ser no `select` (que a meu ver está correto)

Comment: A busca no banco, na verdade eu tenho a condição where para especificar qual registro preciso e seus anterior. Quando informo o where ele irá trazer apenas 1

Comment: Não pode ser essa sua condição que limita o retorno a um apenas?

Comment: Sim, mas como faço para condicionar a busca a trazer o histórico do registro que necessito?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendo se você consulta pelo `p1.id = 3` ele trará todos os registros que existirem e tiverem 3 como `id_anterior`. Não sei se pode acontecer no seu sistema de mais de uma linha ser anterior ao 3. Se sim, acho que você terá que dar mais informações sobre o sistema; se não, o `select` está correto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa de uma [query recursiva](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-with.html) para resolver seu problema.

Estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_historico
(
    id INTEGER,
    id_anterior INTEGER
);

ALTER TABLE tbl_historico ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE tbl_historico ADD CONSTRAINT fk_historico FOREIGN KEY(id_anterior) REFERENCES tbl_historico( id );
```

Dados:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_historico ( id, id_anterior ) VALUES ( 1, NULL );
INSERT INTO tbl_historico ( id, id_anterior ) VALUES ( 2, 1 );
INSERT INTO tbl_historico ( id, id_anterior ) VALUES ( 3, 2 );
```

Solução:

```
WITH RECURSIVE item_historico( id, id_anterior ) AS
(
    SELECT a.id, a.id_anterior FROM tbl_historico a WHERE a.id = 3
    UNION
    SELECT b.id, b.id_anterior FROM tbl_historico b, item_historico a WHERE a.id_anterior = b.id
)
SELECT * FROM item_historico;
```

Referências:

https://coderwall.com/p/whf3-a/hierarchical-data-in-postgres

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-with.html

Comment: Fiz usando a sua referência. Obrigado pela ideia, mas vou deixar em uma única tabela no momento.